# Resolving TypeError str doesn't support the buffer API

Tags: python

I am trying to string matching with the following code, but I run into a TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API. How can this be resolved?

```
 file = open("C:\\Users\\sagars\\Desktop\\newips.json", "rb")
 i = 0
 y = "No information available for that IP"
 for line in file:
     z = line
     print (z)
     if y in z:
         print ("Cannot parse")
     else:
         print ("Can Parse!")
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback error instead of your summary of the message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sagars/PycharmProjects/ShodanJSONReturns/ShodanParserNewAPI.py", line 28, in <module>
    if y in z:
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: @SagarSamtani: Can u shear input file with us or email me vivekbsable@gmail.com because can not replicate issue at my end. One more, do not use variable names with already define by Python interpreter. In your code `file `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file as binary ('rb' instead of 'r') which might be messing it up. This code snippet is a bit more idiomatic:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\sagars\\Desktop\\newips.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    if y in line:
        print ("Cannot parse")
    else:
        print ("Can Parse!")
```